# Angular ng-repeat not being refreshed

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have the following simple directory listing. I wish to upload a file and have the `ng-repeat` list update.

```
<h3>Directory Listing</h3>
<li ng-repeat="file in filearray track by file.id">
    {{file.id}} {{file.filename}}
</li>
```

I have tried pushing a new item into the filearray array in my controller

```
$scope.filearray.push({id:max_id, filename: filename});
```

I have also tried to call the endpoint that provides the directory listing

I have tried with and without `$scope.$apply`, somehow the ng-repeat does not update (also tried with and without track by). Can someone shed some light on ng-repeat and why it does not dynamically update even on an `$scope.$apply` ?

**EDIT : PROBLEM SOLVED**

I had two calls in the main code to the controller ...

```
<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
   <form ng-controller="MainController">
 ...
```

Comment: You might want to try to create a fiddle that reproduces the issue. What you are doing should work, based on the detail you've given. Creating a fiddle will help us help you, and it may even allow you to spot the problem on your own.

Comment: Try opening the Chrome Console (F12 -> console). Make sure that filearray is being populated correctly.

Comment: I tested your problem and i seem not to be finding any problem can you specify [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g35g80Lr/1/)

Comment: Have you actually declared `$scope.filearray`, or you're just trying to push new objects into it?

Comment: As stated above it seems to be working. Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xbuydaqh/2/

Comment: @avrono what is your angular version?

Comment: @JoseRocha Problem now solved, stupid error ... thanks all for the help !